# How to include if statement in dart's TextStyle

Tags: if-statement, flutter, dart, textstyle

I have a TextStyle and a variable **textBold** that can be *true* or *false*. How to implement if in this TextStyle?

```
TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    if ($textBold == true){
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional statement like below.

```
Text(
       "Hello",
        style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: textBold ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal
       ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about this if's form

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that on a constructor at that level. If it only possible when the parameter except at `Map` or `List`.

Example for List:

```dart
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          if(Your Condition)
            YourWidget()
        ],
      )
```

Example for Map:

```dart
final x = {"id":1};
final y = {
  if(Your Condition)
    "SomeKey":"Some Value",
}
```

Comment: I understand that i could do something like that in children, but in style i couldn't

Comment: That isn't supported as of now in Dart